# Why certain .wav files cannot be decoded in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio, wav, web-audio-api

I have a web page which decodes wave files for certain reasons.  Chrome and Safari seem to work fine.  Firefox occasionally is unable to decode the file and gives the error: "The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains invalid content which cannot be decoded successfully."  I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/laertiades/2hav4yLc/2/) which illustrates the issue:

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var source;
function getData() {
  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://mpclubtest.s3.amazonaws.com/Malice_Bass.wav', true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  request.onload = function() {
    var audioData = request.response;
    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        source.buffer = buffer;
        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
      },
      function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});
  }
  request.send();
}
getData();
source.start(0);
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is and if there is any way to circumvent?  Many Thanks.

***EDIT***
Thanks to the substantial contributions of Michael Chaney I was able to implement some javascript which processes the wave so that it can be played in Firefox.  The code trims any part of the "fmt" chunk over 16 bytes.  Code located at:  [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hav4yLc/11/)

```
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
var source;
function getData() {
  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://mpclubtest.s3.amazonaws.com/Malice_Bass.wav', true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
  request.onload = function() {
      var audioData = request.response;
      var dv = new DataView(audioData);
      var junk = 0;
      var position = 12;
      do {
          var header = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Uint8Array(audioData, position, 4));
          var length = dv.getUint32(position + 4, true);
          if (header.trim() === 'fmt') {
              junk = junk + length - 16;
          }
          position = position + 8 + length;
      }while(position < audioData.byteLength);
      var productArray = new Uint8Array(audioData.byteLength - junk);
      productArray.set(new Uint8Array(audioData, 0, 12));
      var newPosition = 12;
      position = 12;
      var fmt_length_spot;
      do {
          var header = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Uint8Array(audioData, position, 4));
          var length = dv.getUint32(position + 4, true);
          if (header.trim() === 'fmt') {
              productArray.set(new Uint8Array(audioData, position, 24), newPosition);
              fmt_length_spot = newPosition + 4;
              newPosition = newPosition + 24;
          }
          else {
              productArray.set(new Uint8Array(audioData, position, length + 8), newPosition);
              newPosition = newPosition + 8 + length;
          }
          position = position + 8 + length;
      }while(position < audioData.byteLength);
      audioData = productArray.buffer;
      dv = new DataView(audioData);
      dv.setUint32(4, audioData.byteLength - 8, true);
      dv.setUint32(fmt_length_spot, 16, true);
      audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
          source.buffer = buffer;
          source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        },
        function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});
    }
    request.send();
}
getData();
source.start(0);
```

Thanks Michael.

Comment: Do you mind if I add this file to my WebAudio Decoder test suite? The idea behind this project is keep checking which browsers fail at decode what kind of audio files? http://notthetup.github.io/decodethis/

Comment: @notthetup, Its all yours.

Comment: I tried this code and it does not solve the problem (I'm using Firefox 52.0.2). It's not surprising though, since it has been written 3 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be the JUNK chunk at the start of the file.  You can run it through sox to clean out extraneous chunks like this:

```
sox Malice_Bass.wav Malice_Bass_simple.wav
```

Here's what my personal parser says about the file:

```
RIFF - WAVE (36467192 bytes)
   JUNK (92)
   bext (602)
         Description:       
         Originator:        Pro Tools
         Originator Ref:    jicj!dad1ofaaaGk
         Origination Date:  2014-09-09
         Origination Time:  20:46:43
         Time Ref Low:      0
         Time Ref High:     0
         BWF Version:       0
         SMPTE UMID Bytes:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
         Coding History:    
   fmt (40)
         Format Tag:        1
         Channels:          2
         Samples per sec:   48000
         Avg bytes per sec: 192000
         Block align:       4
         Bits per sample:   16
   minf (16)
   elm1 (214)
   data (36466048)
   regn (92)
   umid (24)
```

When I clean it up using sox Firefox quits complaining about it but still doesn't play it.  I confirmed that it loads the file but doesn't seem to play it.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  Sounds like a shortcoming with Firefox.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to implement something like your personal parser to run in a browser?

Comment: I think it would but I haven't played with the latest Javascript functionality for doing that.  The WAV format is well-documented and easy to parse.

Comment: Here's the parser that I used to create the above output from the wav file: https://gist.github.com/mdchaney/9adcf006b23a9adc10d6

Comment: When I processed the file with sox, per your instructions, It played in my browser on Firefox:http://jsfiddle.net/laertiades/2hav4yLc/5/

Comment: Yep, plays for me now, too - not sure why I couldn't get it to play before.  Anyway, I recommend that you just clean up your audio in sox.  I handle terabytes of wav and aif files in my business (handling music catalogs, publishing catalogs, libraries, etc.) and the first basic step of handling a file like this is using sox to get it to a simple baseline.  I had a problem with one set of aifs where an empty "anno" chunk caused mac os to ignore the subsequent id3 chunk, making the file metadata effectively disappear.  After that, sox for all of them.

Comment: The problem wasn't with the "Junk" chunk.  It was with the "fmt" chunk.  Firefox doesn't seem to like an "fmt" chunk larger than 16 bytes.  See my new jfiddle above.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I've recently had this problem with Firefox not reading wav files using the browser's audio api and found out that the problem was the bit depth of the audio file which should not exceed 16bits in order to be recognized by Firefox. I've also found out that this is a 8 years old Firefox "bug" which is quite surprising (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=524109)

My soultion was to downgrade any wav files with 32 bit depth to 16bit via sox commandline like this: sox input.wav -b 16 output.wav. You could obviously use ffmpeg or any other application which can do that under Linux.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

That wav file is silent for first 20 seconds. I just downloaded it :

```
wget https://mpclubtest.s3.amazonaws.com/Malice_Bass.wav
```

I tried using chrome and the fiddle was silent, initially I thought
due to fact I'm just using laptop speakers.
A FFT using audacity says its just very low freqs starting after 20 sec of silence.

Web Audio API uses the computer's default sampling rate, which is
typically 44.1kHz   Since the file is using 48 kHz, is your machine
configured with a 48 kHz smple rate ?  If you resample that file which is 48 kHz down to 44.1kHz which is a typical computer's sample rate it'll probably work.

Comment: I have a parser that I wrote for WAVs.  It shows the fmt chunk having 2 channels, 48K samples/second, 16 bits/sample.  It's normal.  Has a JUNK chunk at the beginning and bext, as well as minf, elm1, data, regn, and umid.  Looks like a normal pro tools wav/bwav.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I will look into this. (I'll have to learn how to resample waves).