# Firefox can't decode wav audio format

Tags: javascript, firefox, wav, decoding

Currently I'm creating a game in Javascript and there are audio files included in the game. It works perfectly in Chrome, but Firefox has some problem with decoding some of the audio files.
[Here is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30xhT.png)
I have read a post about the junk chunks at the beginning of the file, but I don't really know how to clean them or what to do with it.

[Link of the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169678/why-certain-wav-files-cannot-be-decoded-in-firefox)

```
// Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_METADATA_ERR (0x806e0006)
audio = new Audio("someaudio.wav")

// It has no problem with it
audio = new Audio("someotheraudio.wav")
```

I experienced that Firefox can decode some audio files, but not all of them.

Comment: the accepted answer doesn't help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why certain .wav files cannot be decoded in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26169678/why-certain-wav-files-cannot-be-decoded-in-firefox)

Comment: Take the files. Run them through an audio editor/converter, and save them in a format that the browser can understand. Audacity can probably do this for you. https://www.audacityteam.org/ I suggest, at most, 16 bit 44,110 khz PCM wav. Otherwise, mp3 is an option that should work across all platforms.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I just simply opened the audio file in Audacity and exported to wav 16bit PCM as you mentioned. Then Firefox had no problem with the exported audio.